# SYMPY's simplify not canceling out variables in a fraction

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to simplify a symbolic expression with sympy.simplify, and the expression looks [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuXg8.png), where all I should be left with is a e^c. But simplify does nothing to that expression. Is there a different function to do that? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

[Edit:]
The code I'm running is:

```
# Given the following probability function: f(c)=4*pi*(m/(2*pi*kb*T))^(3/2)*c^2*exp(-1/2*m*c^2/(kb*T))
# The ratio of the fraction of molecules with the rms speed, over 3*c_rms
# Where: c_rms=sqrt(3*kb*T/m)
# So the ratio is: f(c_rms)/f(3*c_rms)

from sympy import *

f = Symbol('f')
c = Symbol('c')
kb = Symbol('kb')
T = Symbol('T')
m = Symbol('m')

def f(c):
    f=4*pi*(m/(2*pi*kb*T))**(3/2)*c**2*exp(-1/2*m*c**2/(kb*T))
    return f

cr1= (3*kb*T/m)**(1/2)
cr3 = 3*cr1
p1 = f(cr1)
p3= f(cr3)
ratio = simplify(p1/p3)
print(ratio)
```

Where ratio is the expression to be simplified.

Comment: Please, edit the question and add your code so that we can understand what's wrong!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `1/2` as an exponent (or as the first operation in a product of factors) you create the python float 0.5. You will get a simpler result when you use `S(1)/2` to create the rational `1/2` -- simplify will not, then, even be necessary:

```py
from sympy import *

f = Symbol('f')
c = Symbol('c')
kb = Symbol('kb')
T = Symbol('T')
m = Symbol('m')

def f(c):
    f=4*pi*(m/(2*pi*kb*T))**(S(3)/2)*c**2*exp(-S(1)/2*m*c**2/(kb*T))
    return f

cr1= (3*kb*T/m)**(S(1)/2)
cr3 = 3*cr1
p1 = f(cr1)
p3= f(cr3)
ratio = p1/p3
```

`ratio` is `exp(12)/9`.